# display multi columns from the one table

Tags: php, sql, pivot

List item

I am new to php and I am trying to do the following:

```
empid  Salary   Month
1      2342     Jan 
1      3234     Feb
1      3445     Mar
2      3222     Jan
2      3342     Feb
3      3352     Mar
```

How do I display it as:

```
empid  jan   feb    mar
1      2342  3234  3445
2      3222  3342  3352
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Post some code

Comment: Which SQL? MySQL? SQL Server etc..

Comment: What about if there are more than one salary for `January`, e.g. for 2011, 2012, 2013 (after few months) etc. I think you should extend your table with a `year` field. I don't think you are wanting to display a sum for each month, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *pivot* rows into columns like so:

```
SELECT
  emp_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN month_end = 'jan' THEN salary END) 'jan',
  MAX(CASE WHEN month_end = 'feb' THEN salary END) 'feb',
  MAX(CASE WHEN month_end = 'mar' THEN salary END) 'mar'
FROM Emps
GROUP BY emp_id
```

And this is the standard way to do this. It should work for all RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify your RDBMS but if you are using MySQL and you have an unknown number of values that you are returning, then you use a prepared statement:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when month_end = ''',
      month_end,
      ''' then salary end) AS ',
      month_end
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yourTable;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Emp_Id, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM yourtable 
                    GROUP BY Emp_Id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Or you can hard-code all of the months via a static version similar to @Mahmoud's answer

If you are working in an RDBMS that has a `PIVOT` function similar to SQL Server, then you can use the following:

```
select *
from
(
    select emp_id, salary, month_end
    from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
    max(salary)
    for month_end in ([jan], [feb], [mar])
) p
```

Or using dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(month_end) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT emp_id, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select emp_id, salary, month_end
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(salary)
                for month_end in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies, Have it sorted now. You have all been a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp_id AS emp_id , 
[jan], [feb], [mar]
FROM
(SELECT month_end , salary 
    FROM Emps) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(salary )
FOR month_end IN ([jan], [feb], [mar])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: please try with pivot function